# How to check if collection contains any element from other collection in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, collections, apache-commons

Title says it all, what is the best practice for finding out if collection contains any element of other collection?

In java I would execute it like this

```
CollectionUtils.containsAny(a, b)
```

using common apache collection utils, where variables a/b are collections.

How to implement this behavior in scala? Or is there library like CollectionUtils from above?

I dont want to use the common-apache library because i would have to convert scala collection to java collection.

Comment: Is there a difference between a scala collection and a java one?

Comment: @RobertMoskal  Yes - and in fact scala has two completely separate collections hierarchies: immutable and mutable.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use a combination of `exists(p: T => Boolean):Boolean` and `contains(elem: A1):Boolean` :

```
val a = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
val b = List(11,22,33,44,55,6)

a.exists(b.contains) // true
```

Comment: That makes sense... but I'd argue it doesn't make for much readability 

Answer (score 22):

**Intersect**

```
val a = Seq(1,2,3) ; val b = Seq(2,4,5)
a.intersect(b)
res0: Seq[Int] = List(2)

// to include the test:
a.intersect(b).nonEmpty  // credit @Lukasz
```

Comment: Not sure why it got a downvote. It's the obvious answer

Comment: It could look cleaner as `a.intersect(b).nonEmpty`.

Comment: The obvious answer is the other one, @TheArchetypalPaul. Anyways, I didn't downvote, just didn't vote.

Comment: Since the question is actually "do the two arrays have any elements in common" I still feel intersect of the obvious answer. It certainly didn't need a down vote. Imo obviously

Comment: @Łukasz  Thx for the nonEmpty (vs !isEmpty)

Comment: Isn't it wasteful to have to create an intersection just to check whether it is nonEmpty? I think that is why people vote for the other solution.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`disjoint()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint(java.util.Collection,java.util.Collection)) from the standard Java `Collections` utilities can determine if two collections contain any common members.  If the collections are not disjoint, then they contain at least one common element.

Internally, `Collections.disjoint()` checks if either collection is a `Set` and optimizes accordingly.

```
import collection.JavaConverters._

val a = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
val b = List(11,22,33,44,55,6)

!java.util.Collections.disjoint(a.asJava, b.asJava)  // true
```

Although this is still converting the Scala collection to a Java collection.  On the plus side, the extra apache commons library isn't needed.